# VS Code SSH user name cannot include the character \

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

In Windows remote host I have username like `WORK\username`, and when I connect from Windows console:

```
ssh WORK\username@hostname
```

Everything is fine. Also I can connect from WSL with double slash:

```
ssh WORK\\username@hostname
```

But I can not connect from VS Code. I have an error:

```
Could not establish connection to "hostname": SSH user name cannot include the character \.
```

What to do with it, I have tried to escape the slash in different ways, but it was not work.

My VS Code version is `1.59.1`.

Comment: You could try to use the ~/.ssh/config. Add your host and define the USER there

Comment: @jeb I have already tried and I got the same

Comment: Interesting, I tested it with the same version (but on a linux system) and it works with a user name `kranker\user`. In the .ssh/config file are the entries `HOST myServer` and `USER kranker\user`

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved, when the username is stored in ~/.ssh/config

```
HOST myServer
   hostname example.com
   USER WORK\username
```

Obviously the connection should be started then from the Remote Explorer.

Tested successfully with VS Code version 1.59.1 on Windows and also Linux